# Error 404 webpage not found when submitting form

Tags: html, eclipse, servlets, backend

I keep getting this error when I hit the submit button, the doPost() method in the servlet is not getting called.
I am using Eclipse and running the project on an Apache server. Upon hitting submit, the page should be redirected to ShowConfirmMake.ftl which basically just prints out that the user has registered successfully.
Here is the code for the servlet:

```
public class UUGUI extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * doGet contains the register form
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        
        // set pagetitle und navtype
        request.setAttribute("navtype", "unregistereduser");
        request.setAttribute("pagetitle", "register");

        // Dispatch request to template engine
        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/templates/defaultWebpageuu.ftl").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Contains handling of Register call
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.print("not registering");
        request.setAttribute("navtype", "unregistereduser");
        

        // Check wether the call is insertOffer or not
        if (request.getParameter("action").equals("register")) {

            // Append parameter of request
            String name = (String) request.getParameter("name");
            String email = (String) request.getParameter("email");
            int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));

            // Call application to insert offer
            new MRApplication().RegisterUser(name, email, age);
            
            // Dispatch message to template engine
            try {
                request.setAttribute("pagetitle", "register");
                request.setAttribute("message", "Successful Registered");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/templates/showConfirmMake.ftl").forward(request, response);

            } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Call doGet if request is not equal to insertOffer
        } else
            
            doGet(request, response);

    }
}
```

And the html code for the form is:

```
<#include "header.ftl">

<b>Welcome to our little demonstration on the MR Webapp</b><br><br>

<form method="POST" action="unregistereduser?action=register">
    <fieldset id="registeruser">
        <legend>Required Information</legend>
        <div>
            <label>name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>age</label>
            <input type="number" name="age" required min = "18">
        </div>
        
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<#include "footer.ftl">
```

Comment: *Why* should hitting submit end up calling this servlet class? It's not shown here.

Comment: How do I fix that?